# Merge multiple trees with a depth of one

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have multiple subtrees which consist of a root element and multiple children. A root of a subtree can be anothers children and a children of a subtree can be anothers root.

In the end there could be multiple completely seperated trees.

Example:

```
root1
  |-child11
  |-root3

root2
  |-child21
  |-root1
  |-child23

root3
  |-child31
```

Should result to:

```
root2
  |-child21
  |
  |-root1
  |   |-child11
  |   |-root3
  |       |-child31
  |
  |-child23
```

Is there a good algorithm to solve this? I only found solutions for binary trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep in each node a:

- hash table (or a linked list + hash table, if order is important) for the children
- A pointer to the parent (or `None`)

Additionally, keep a hash table mapping node ids to lists of nodes.

---

While there is a list in the latter hash table of length greater than 1, find which tree should be merged into which other tree.

Answer (score 0):

Define a node structure as having a parent node and set of children.

Keep a set of all unique nodes.

When you process all little trees, populate the children set for each parent, and point each child back to its parent. (Along the way add each new unseen node to your set on uniques.)

At the end walk the set if uniques. Any node with no parent is the root of a rebuilt tree.